# Percentages value in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am looking for:

- the percentage of players who are in weight type thin,
- the percentage of players who are in weight type normal,
- the percentage of players who are in weight type overweight,
- the percentage of players who are in weight type obese.

All of them are listed in the IMC column.

This is my dataset:
[image]

I don't know Python well. I get the percentage of each row, but it does not group by group (thin, normal, overweight, obese)

This is my current code:

```py
(df.groupby('IMC').size() / df['IMC'].count()) * 100
```

Comment: can you post the whole python code, please?

Comment: Can you include few records from the dataframe? It would be easy to replicate

Answer (score 0):

that's because your groupby is reversed:

```
df.groupby('IMC')
```

will group by the weight, not by the category. If you flip your code to

```
df.groupby('clasificacion_oms')
```

you will then get all the players grouped by their weight type. Then you can divide the count in each group by the total number of players to get your percentage.

Does that give you what you need? If not, please post your code so we can provide more detail.